# Interface value is null when called in MVP by using Dagger2

Tags: java, android, mvp, dagger-2

I'm working with `Firebase push notification` structure `MVP` using `Dagger2.
since I like coding more flexible with better logic.

So now, My issue is the `notificationView` interface I only can get `null` value from it even I already set `notificationView` value in `BaseTopActivity` by using `Dagger 2` (@inject `BaseTopPresenter`) + `MVP` (`BaseTopPresenter`)

Please help me consider to get `notificationView` value (should not `null`),

Thank you,

p/s : Below is file details.

`NotificationView interface`

```
public interface BaseTopView extends BaseView {

   interface NotificationView {
        void onUpdateNotifications(RemoteMessage remoteMessage, int notifyId);
    }
}
```

`Component`

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = {AppComponent.class})
public interface Component {

    // Activities
    void inject(BaseTopActivity activity);

    // Services
    void inject(FirebaseMsgService service);

}
```

`BaseActivity.java`

```
@ActivityScope
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseView {

/**
 * Dagger 2
 */
Component Component;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Dagger 2
    Component = DaggerComponent.builder()
    .appComponent(MainApplication.getAppComponent(this)).build();
}

}
```

`BaseTopActivity.java` is where I set interface `notificationView` value

```
@ActivityScope
public abstract class BaseTopActivity extends BaseActivity implements BaseTopView.NotificationView {

@Inject
BaseTopPresenter baseTopPresenter;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Dagger2
         */
        getComponent().inject(this);

        // notification view : print : Activity Name extend BaseTopActivity

        Timber.e(" setView " + notificationView);

        // BaseTopPresenter value == BaseTopPresenter@2353dad4
        baseTopPresenter.setView(notificationView);

     }
}
```

`BaseTopPresenter interface` is where I set interface `notificationView` value

```
public void setView(BaseTopView.NotificationView notificationView) {
        // GOT VALUE ALREADY HERE, NOT NULL
        Timber.e(BaseTopPresenter.class.getSimpleName() + " setView " + notificationView);

        this.notificationView = notificationView;
    }

    public BaseTopView.NotificationView getView() {
        return notificationView;
    }
```

Issue will appear in this file where I get interface `notificationView` value : `FirebaseService.java`

```
public class FirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

// Dagger2
Component Component;

@Inject
BaseTopPresenter presenter;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    MainApplication applicationContext = (MainApplication) getApplicationContext();
    if (applicationContext != null) {
        // RUN
        Timber.e("onMessageReceived --- inject ");

        // Dagger 2
        Component = DaggerComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(MainApplication.getAppComponent(this)).build();
        asukabuComponent.inject(this);
    } else Timber.e("applicationContext == null");

    // VALUE in getView() IS NULL HERE, NO CRASH WITH PRESENTER
    // BaseTopPresenter value == BaseTopPresenter@333cb1bf
    Timber.e("getView " + presenter.getView());

    if (remoteMessage != null)  sendNotification(remoteMessage);
}
```

***UPDATE*** : BaseTopPresenter value is different. I think somewhere I inject Dagger2 is wrong.

`MainApplication.java`

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

/**
 * Dagger 2
 */
private AppComponent appComponent;

/**
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static AppComponent getAppComponent(Context context) {
    return ((MainApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).appComponent;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Dagger 2
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .networkModule(new NetworkModule(getString(R.string.base_url)))
            .build();
}
}
```

Comment: can you define `AppComponent ` in Application Class see here more details https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sampleapp/base/SampleApplication.java

Comment: @Saveen : Could I know what do u mean? I also update the file u want :)

Comment: Can you review my sample what you missing

Comment: Using this sample repository you can learn more about MVP mixture with dagger: http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you create *another* BaseTopPresenter when inject it into FirebaseMsgService. And obviously there is no view attached. You could make BaseTopPresenter singleton (check for @Singleton annotation). But on this case you should be very careful with view (e.c. Activity) lifecycle.